# Quando devo escolher a opção de "Editar" na fila de análise de fechamento?

Tags: debate, suporte, filas-de-análise

Existe uma opção de "Editar" na fila de análise de fechamento, mas para que serve essa opção?

Quando devo escolhê-la e quando não deve escolhê-la?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao escolher **Editar** em uma fila de análises de encerramento é a mesma coisa de dizer que você garante que após a edição a pergunta merece ficar aberta, pois ao final da sua edição a pergunta simplesmente sai da fila de análises, tornando impossível que outros usuários continuem analisando a pergunta e decidindo democraticamente se ela deve ou não ser encerrada.

### Quando editar

Somente tome a ação de editar uma resposta que está na fila de encerramento caso você consiga corrigir **todos** os problemas dela ao ponto dela ser merecedora de não mais ser fechada.

Exemplos:

- Quando a pergunta possui um código que ficou invisível aos usuários por não estar formatado adequadamente, deixando a pergunta sem sentido ; ou
- Usuário fez a pergunta em outro idioma e você resolveu traduzir.

PS: ninguém é obrigado a traduzir, na verdade eu até desaconselho tal prática, mas se você sentir que é necessário e estiver disposto a fazer a tradução siga em frente.

### Quando não editar

Não edite uma publicação apenas para tirar saudações e coisas do tipo. Isso não é um motivo para fechar uma pergunta, consequentemente ela foi parar na fila de análises por outro motivo. Corrigir isso não vai melhorá-la ao ponto de evitar que ela deva ser fechada, e você estará retirando a chance de outros usuários darem o voto nela.

### Leia o menu

[image: menu da fila de encerramento]

No menu tem a explicação do motivo o qual deve-se escolher tal opção.

"**Editar** se esta pergunta puder ser melhorada de modo que não precise ser encerrada"

### Conclusão

A ideia dessa publicação é instruir os desavisados a usarem corretamente a opção de editar uma pergunta na fila de encerremanto. Entretanto, apesar de eu acreditar que esse pode ser um erro fácil de ser cometido por alguns usuários existem alguns outros que simplesmente não fazem a menor ideia do que estão fazendo e clicam em qualquer coisa na fila de análise pois estão única e exclusivamente em busca das medalhas.

Logo, para o segundo caso não adianta muito avisar (até mesmo por que provavelmente nem vão ler o aviso aqui), por isso eu volto a tocar no assunto **aviso/punição por meio da moderação**. Eu diria que é justo que as pessoas que erram na fila de análises comecem a receber avisos, e no caso de reincidências recebam punições, pois essas pessoas prejudicam a comunidade e tenho certeza que assim como eu existem vários outros usuários que se sentem prejudicados por esse tipo de atitude.